# When i am trying to execute getaccountnumber method,getting following error mentioned in the image

Tags: java

Method `getbalance` and `getaccountnumber` are not getting called when i am calling them from the `Main` class.

```
public String getaccountnumber(String accountnumber)
{
    return accountnumber;
}   
public void setaccountnumber(String accountnumber)
{
    this.accountnumber = accountnumber;
}
    
public double getbalance(double balance)
{   
    return balance;
}
```

I am getting "method cannot be Applied to given types".

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
        System.out.println(sanjay.getaccountnumber());
        System.out.println(sanjay.getbalance());
```

[image: when i am trying to execute getaccountnumber,getting following error]

Comment: Those methods, according to their declaration, require a parameter. You are not passing a parameter. So the code does not compile.

Comment: I am passing the parameters through the constructor.

Comment: You declare the methods with a parameter. Why?

Comment: public account( String accountnumber,double balance, String name,String email,String phone)
 {
  System.out.println("constructor with parameters is created");
 }

Comment: Please follow any beginner tutorial on programming with java and you will find your answer.

Comment: In the above constructor i am passing parameters

Comment: Thank you @f1sh .I should not have declared get methods with parameter and i have done and you rectified me .Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out in the comments, you need to pass the parameters into the methods, it also looks like you need to create an instance of your class.

Assuming your class with the account methods is like the one below:

```java
public class sanjay
{
  public String getaccountnumber(String accountnumber)
  {
    return accountnumber;
  }   
  public void setaccountnumber(String accountnumber)
  {
    this.accountnumber = accountnumber;
  }
    
  public double getbalance(double balance)
  {   
    return balance;
  }
}
```

You would need to create an instance of the class `sanjay` as follows:

```java
sanjay mySanjayInstance = new sanjay();
```

Then you can call the methods with the parameters:

```java
mySanjayInstance.getaccountnumber("myaccountnumber");
mySanjayInstance.setaccountnumber("myaccountnumber");
mySanjayInstance.getbalance(0.4);
```

As such your main method would look like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  sanjay mySanjayInstance = new sanjay();


  System.out.println(mySanjayInstance.getaccountnumber("myaccountnumber"));
  System.out.println(mySanjayInstance.getbalance(0.4));
}
```

Taking a guess it seems like you intended to create a class that you set details on, and then retrieve them (with getter and setter methods). As such you would want to use some class variables and remove the parameters from the getter methods.

```java
public class sanjay
{
  private String accountnumber;
  private double balance;

  public String getaccountnumber()
  {
    return accountnumber;
  }   
  public void setaccountnumber(String accountnumber)
  {
    this.accountnumber = accountnumber;
  }
    
  public double getbalance()
  {   
    return balance;
  }

  public void setbalance(double balance)
  {
    this.balance = balance;
  }
}
```

Now your usage would look like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  // Create an instance of the `sanjay` class.
  sanjay mySanjayInstance = new sanjay();

  // Set the properties on the object we just created via the setters.
  mySanjayInstance.setaccountnumber("myaccountnumber");
  mySanjayInstance.setbalance(0.4);

  // Retrieve the properties via the getters.
  System.out.println(mySanjayInstance.getaccountnumber());
  System.out.println(mySanjayInstance.getbalance());
}
```

Some observations that can make your life much easier in the long run;

- Consider using SnakeCase for class names (so `Sanjay` instead of `sanjay`).
- And snakeCase for methods and variable names (including parameters), so `getAccountNumber` instead of `getaccountnumber`.

Comment: I really appreciate your suggestions and i will follow it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Account 
{
    public String getaccountnumber()
    {
        return accountnumber;
    }   

    
    public double getbalance()
    {   
        return balance;
    }
}
```

Here is the answer. This will work but it will not help you really understand what you are doing wrong. To really understand the concept of "Classes", "Objects" and "Parameters" I still recommend you follow an introductory tutorial for Java of at least 5 hours.

Comment: It really helped me.I thank you for your valuable time.